# Layout fields with no margin between them on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

How do I prevent extra space between two fields:

```
VerticalFieldManager _fieldManagerMiddle = 
    new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
LabelField field = new LabelField("Title");
CustomFieldList list = new CustomFieldList ();

_fieldManagerMiddle.add(field);
_fieldManagerMiddle.add(list);
```

Comment: Can you describe your desired outcome and what is happening instead? There are spaces between the LabelField and the CustomFieldList? It's not immediately clear from your question. You can format code by leading with 4 spaces to make it easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I get spaces between the LabelField and the CustomFieldList and also in CustomFieldList between rows.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the space between two managers you can try [negative VerticalFieldManager and HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the margin to zero?  Margin is just a property on the field, but managers use it to decide the minimum space between two fields during layout.

```
field.setMargin(0,0,0,0);
list.setMargin(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom manager .
inside the sublayout method you can position the contents as per your requirement and choice